# About the function NCONC in Common Lisp

Tags: function, common-lisp, stack-overflow, circular-list

I got a real stack overflow by typing the following codes

```
(setf l1 (list 1))

(setf l2 (list 2))

(nconc l1 l2)

(nconc l2 l1)
```

Oops...

Is that a bug?

Comment: Set `*PRINT-LENGTH*` to something like `5`.

Comment: You intended to create a circular list, didn't you?

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I know. NCONC will return the first list after the operation.

Comment: **NCONC** isn't overflowing the stack,  the REPL is when trying to print the value.

Comment: You're destructively modified the first list so that the second list is appended to it, and that list has the first list destructively appended to it. This results in a circular list.

Comment: Or set [`*print-circle*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) to `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such. Printing a never-ending list won't ever be a good thing.

Set `*print-circle*` to `T` to see the structure of the list.

It's no more a bug than the never-ending nature of `#1=(foo . #1#)`